# Replace numbers in string with identifying placeholder

Tags: php, regex, replace, placeholder

I have these (example and not working) two strings:

```
$text1 = "S0 64000";
$text2 = "C0 64000";
```

and my goal is create:

```
$newtext1 = "S%d0% %d1%";
$newtext2 = "C%d0% %d1%";
```

Effectively, the first number (`0`) should be replaced by `%d0%` to represent the first occurring numeric placeholder, and the second number (`64000`) should be replaced by `%d1%` to represent the second occurring placeholder.

So, in the future, I know that in `%d0%` there's the first number I will get, and in `%d1%` there will be the second (DIFFERENT) number I will get.

In case of `$text1="S0 0"`, the expected result is: `$newtext1 = "S%d0% %d0%"`

If for example `$text1 = S10 455`, I will calculate `text2` to automatically return `C10 455`.

I repeat, this is an example string where I found this problem, the string can be also a long text with no numbers, so the string are not always with the same syntax.

My flow at the moment is this:

```
$text1 = "S0 64000";
$text2 = "C0 64000";

$pattern = '/\d+/';

/* get the count and the number founded storing in $matchOriginal */
$cnt = preg_match_all($pattern,$text1,$matchOriginal);

if($cnt == 0){
    dd("no numbers"); //just for test
}
/* I get the numbers founded in $text2
preg_match_all($pattern, $text2, $matchTransl);

/* I check that each two arrays of numbers are equal, maybe can be done in a better way */
$original = array_diff($matchOriginal[0],$matchTransl[0]);
$transl = array_diff($matchTransl[0],$matchOriginal[0]);

if(empty($original) && empty($transl)){
} else {
    dd("different arrays");
}

/* I prepare two arrays
    $replacement will be %d0%, %d1% the number will depends by the number presence on 
    the string
    $values will be the array with the numbers i will replace with $replacement*/

foreach ($matchOriginal[0] as $key => $value) {
    $replacement[] = "%d".$key."%";
    $values[] = $value;  
}

/* here the magic */
$newText1 = str_replace($values, $replacement, $text1);
$newText2 = str_replace($values, $replacement, $text2);
```

But I have a problem, for as the flow is working at the moment, having the `$values` and `$replacement` array like this:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => "0"
  1 => "64000"
]
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => "%d0%"
  1 => "%d1%"
]
```

The function `str_replace` will start to replace all the `"0"` with `%d0%` and the resulting string will be:

```
$text1 ="S%d0% 64%d0%%d0%%d0%"
```

Any better solution instead to order the arrays from the higest number to the lower?

Maybe I can use preg_replace, but how can I build the regex expression?

Comment: Make sure you have a bunch of test cases executed automatically (TDD).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to improve the performance of this code is probably by using the preg_replace_callback()-function. This function allows you to search for a regex in a string, and call a function for every match. This function then returns the replacement. This avoids running multiple str_replace() operations over the string, which can be costly for large strings.

Secondly, we can use a capture group in the regex to avoid the use of explode(). I.e. by changing the regex from /{ITEM-.*?}/ to /{ITEM-(.*?)}/ we can ensure that we get the matched item identifier directly.

Applying those two modifications, we would end up with something like:

```
$content = 'Here is the item list {ITEM-100}  {ITEM-110}  {ITEM-200}';    
function get_replacement($matches) {
    $value = $matches[1]; // Index 1 is the first capture group, which contains our item number.
    return get_item_card($value);
}
$content = preg_replace_callback('/{ITEM-(.*?)}/', 'get_replacement', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: mmmh...Your code is not so clear, what do the get_item_card? In secondary way the function get_replacemenr should accept a passed "matched" not the founded by the preg_replace_callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `preg_replace_callback`. If you stick the found matches into an array, then you can look up their index in there again when you process the next match.

```
$text1 = "S0 64000 0 145 0 0 3";
$c = [];
$newtext1 = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($matches) use (&$c) {
    if(false !== ($idx = array_search($matches[0], $c))) {
      return '%d'.$idx.'%';
    }
    else {
        $c[] = $matches[0];
        return '%d'.(count($c)-1).'%';
    }
}, $text1);
unset($c);
```

Result: `S%d0% %d1% %d0% %d2% %d0% %d0% %d3%`

Comment: Is not suitable this solution, cause with the string S0 64000 0 the result is S%d0% %d1% %d2% when should be S%d0% %d1% %d0%

Comment: Ah, I did not actually understand your problem description then. I edited the answer, this should do it now, I think?

Comment: Since it gets passed by reference, I included `unset($c);` at the end (as one always should) - I suppose you did not initialize it with `$c = [];` again then, before you called `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: yes, I delete the comment cause I seen this two second after, I will test it for a while, at the moment thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After calling `preg_match_all()`, iterate the matches array; if any matches were found, then populate an array of find and replacement values as an associative array.  Then call `strtr()` -- it seeks out the longest (most appropriate) strings to translate and does not replace replacements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S9ipQ))

```
$text = "S0 64000 0 145 0 0 3";

if (preg_match_all('/\d+/', $text, $m)) {
    $translations = [];
    $i = -1;
    foreach ($m[0] as $v) {
        $translations[$v] ??= '%d' . ++$i . '%';
    }
    $text = strtr($text, $translations);
}
echo $text;
// S%d0% %d1% %d0% %d2% %d0% %d0% %d3%
```

P.s. Alternatively, I could have used `preg_split('/\D+/',  $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` to pull a flat array of numbers from the text.

P.p.s. `preg_replace_callback()` can be used without using variables outside of the function body's scope -- just use the `static` declaration so that the variable can be persistently referenced and yet not overwritten/clear on each iteration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1ODll)) ([More compact](https://3v4l.org/cYo2c))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/\d+/',
         function($m) {
             static $i = -1;
             static $translations = [];
             $translations[$m[0]] ??= '%d' . ++$i . '%';
             return $translations[$m[0]];
         },
         $text
     );
```